# Windows sounds get muted on startup

Tags: windows-10, audio, system-sounds

I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve for some time now:

Whenever my computer starts, Windows sounds are muted:

[image]

I can unmute them manually but as you can imagine, it gets really boring having to do so each time.

Comment: System is already up to date actually so ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of failing to fix it up, I finally did, disabling SPDIF device magically fixed it!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following methods to see if the issue can be resolved.

1. Click Start and insert **Services** and open it. Locate to **Windows Audio**-> select **restart** and then reboot your machine to see if the issue can be resolved.
2. If the issue still existed, please click Start, insert **troubleshoot settings** and open it. Select **Additional troubleshooters**-> locate to **Playing Audio**->click **Run the troubleshooter**-> select the device you want to troubleshoot -> select Next, then click **No, Do not open Audio Enhancements** and click **Next** to see if the issue can be resolved.

Comment: You led me to the solution, I've reset every tab settings in audio, rebooted, works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved.
Go to System > Sound > All sound devices. Click the output device that you are using. Under general > Audio, change it to "Allow" for "Allow apps and Windows to use the device for audio."